# Wrong ListView item is passed by the intent

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am using BackendLess backend service, but my prob is (i guess) more to android/java. So even if u are not familiar with BackendLess, i guess u can help, if u know of course :)

I have there a Fragment that calls and opens a DialogFragment with a ListView.
Using there an iterator to retrieve the data. It brings each column from the data table as an Array. 
I set an onClickedItemListener that when item is clicked, it send the value to a TextView in the Fragment it was called from.

The data comes in the wrong order - didnt get how to do a sortBy, that connects to the bigger prob i have there - 
There is a column there named "PropertyTypes". It holds 4 strings, which are coming out in the opposite order that i need. I want the "A" first, and get:
"D"
"C"
"B"
"A"
ok, so far no big deal, i guess can be sorted out with a sortBy that i just dont know how to do.
But... what happens is that it sends the wrong value to the TextView, meaning, for example, when i press "C" it set "A" on the TextView and so on, and, when i press the last one, in this case "A", the app is crashing...

What the hell is going on there?? :))

Here is the code - 
The DialogFragment code:

```
public class OptionDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ListView mylist;
    TextView chosenProperty;
    TextView presentListItem;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //mylist.addHeaderView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.option_dialog_header, null, false));
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.option_dialog_content, null, false);
    mylist = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    View headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.option_dialog_header, mylist, false);
    headerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });
    mylist.addHeaderView(headerView);
    View footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.option_dialog_footer, mylist, false);
    footerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });
    mylist.addFooterView(footerView);
    chosenProperty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.chosenProperty);

    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    final ArrayList<String> propertyTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<Integer> numOfRoomies = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Backendless.Data.of(DialogOptions.class).find(new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<DialogOptions>>() {
        @Override
        public void handleResponse(final BackendlessCollection<DialogOptions> dialogOptions) {
            final Iterator<DialogOptions> iterator = dialogOptions.getCurrentPage().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                DialogOptions dialogOptionsObject = iterator.next();
                propertyTypes.add(dialogOptionsObject.getPropertyTypes());
                // numOfRoomies.add( dialogOptionsObject.getNumOfRoomies() );

            }

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.dialog_option_list_item, R.id.presentListItem, propertyTypes);
            mylist.setAdapter(adapter);

            mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    String chosenItem = propertyTypes.get(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("chosenItem", chosenItem);
                    getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(
                            getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);

                    dismiss();

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
            // TODO: make sure to log the exception, just in case
        }
    });

}
```

}

This is the Relevant code in the Fragment that calls the DialogFragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.find_a_place, container, false);
        chosenProperty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.chosenProperty);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final LinearLayout propertTypes = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.propertyTypes);

        propertTypes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(getActivity(), "OptionDialog");

            }

        });

    }

    private void showDialog(FragmentActivity activity, String optionDialog) {

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

        DialogFragment dialog = new OptionDialogFragment();
        dialog.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
        dialog.show(manager, "OptionDialog");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch(requestCode) {
            case 0:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    if(data!=null){
                        // set value to your TextView
                        chosenProperty.setText(data.getStringExtra("chosenItem"));
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Reference :-
https://backendless.com/feature-47-loading-data-objects-from-server-with-sorting/

To Sort while retrieving Object use :-

`QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions();
queryOptions.addSortByOption( "created ASC" );
dataQuery.setQueryOptions( queryOptions );`

Use Query as below:-

```
// fetch restaurants


Backendless.Data.of( Restaurant.class ).find( dataQuery, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<Restaurant>>(){
```

Comment: Hi Nidhin. Thanks a lot for your answer about the sorting! Will give a try now

Comment: Ok guys - i got it after the help from Nidhin, which fixed the sorting prob, what i did is this:
in "String chosenItem = propertyTypes.get(position);" i  added "-1" after position, and that fixed the value going to the TextView.
I guess its because i added a header and a footer to the ListView, so it messed up the counting there.. So far so good...